# NSMutableURLRequest POST string data with URLencode， return “414 Request-URI Too Large"

Tags: iphone

When I use NSMutableURLRequest to POST string data with URLencode， return “414 Request-URI Too Large”，How I can do?
return error message as below:

```
<html>
<head><title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>414 Request-URI Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.6</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and I use NSMutableURLRequest Setting as below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[urlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: I use [urlStr length] to get the length is 42833.

Comment: Why such a large string?

Comment: I think the better question is why is the data both in the URL and in the POST body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urlstr cannot be both URL and POST data. You must split it at the ? or the first & into URL and POST data.

Comment: hi ott, How to split it at the ? or the first & into URL and POST data? http://*.*.*/m/?r=Iphone/Suggest&C=%@&PN=%@&Flag=%@   and the Suggest&C=%@ data is too long, how I can split?

Comment: Use [urlStr componentsSeperatedByString:@"&"] to split it into an array, array[0] is the url. Then rebuild the post-data from array[1]..array[n] with [array componentsJoinedByString:@"&"] again. Of course it's much easier if you just omitted the url when building the post-data.